# Why my code doesn't work when I use go live?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

signupForm.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" class="form" method="post">
        
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br><br>

        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br><br>

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password"><br><br>

        <button class="signup">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

signupForm.js

```
    const express=require("express")
    const mongoose=require('mongoose')
    const bodyParser=require("body-parser")
    
    const app=express()
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
    
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/SignUpData",{useNewUrlParser:true},{useUnifiedTopology:true})
    
    const signupSchema={
        username:String,
        email:String,
        password:String,
    }
    
    const SignupInfo=mongoose.model("SignupInfo",signupSchema)
    
    app.get('/signupForm.html',(req,res)=>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname+'/signupForm.html')
    })
    
    app.post('/signupForm.html',(req,res)=>{
        let signup=new SignupInfo({
            username:req.body.username,
            email:req.body.email,
            password:req.body.password,
        })
        signup.save();
        res.redirect('/signupForm.html')
    })
    
    app.listen(5500,()=>{
        console.log("Server on 5500")
    })
```

This works just fine , if I type localhost:5500/signupForm.html in browser and give data , the data gets stored in the mongodb.

but if I go through

login.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Login/Signup</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
        <div class="loginBody">
            <div class="login_heading">
                All-In Education
            </div>
            <div class="login">
                <div class="login1">
                    <a href="loginForm.html">Login</a>
                </div>
                <div class="login2">
                    <a href="loginForm.html">Click if account exists</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="signup">
                <div class="signup1">
                    <a href="signupForm.html">Signup</a>
                </div>
                <div class="signup2">
                    <a href="signupForm.html">Click for new account</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

if I click use go-live(it is a live-server extension by Ritwick Dey in Visual Studio Code) in visual studio code with login.html file , then click on signup link , the page redirects to signupForm.html , but when I try to feed the data and click on sign up button, it says
"This page isn’t working
If the problem continues, contact the site owner.

HTTP ERROR 405 " , with url " http://127.0.0.1:5500/signupForm.html ".

Comment: What is _"go-live"_? Is it a built-in webserver? Your Node.js application server is probably not running. There is no route for `login.html` in `signupForm.js` so it seems like it's a different server.

Comment: error 405 - the server has rejected the specific HTTP method it's using - does this "go-live" handle POST request?

Comment: it is a live-server extension by Ritwick Dey in Visual Studio Code

Comment: [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) and [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) are two completely different applications.

Comment: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/541 https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/66 https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/54 etc

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant VS code.

Comment: _"go-live"_ starts a webserver. It's not your Node.js backend server. It doesn't know how to handle requests. Why do you even want to use a dev webserver if you have your own application server for this?

Comment: most "solutions" to this issue are **Same issue. Just stopped using Live Server in VS Code.** not surprising really - the code for hasn't been touched by ritwick in over 2 years

Comment: I'm very new to node. SO Please tell me what should I do if I cant use go live? If I open the login.html file directly in the browser it still dont work. I dont get the 405 error , but my data doesnt get stored in the mongodbcompass.

Comment: Add a route for `login.html` in your application server and start it with `node signupForm.js`. Don't use this live server.

Comment: @JaromandaX Could you explain how node-http-server could connect to Mongo DB?

Comment: @jabaa - sorry - I'm just quoting lines from the issues on that repo ... clearly the OP isn't reading them, so I thought I'd do it for him

Comment: " Add a route for login.html in your application server and start it with node signupForm.js. Don't use this live server. " How do I do that?

Comment: First: do you have an application server?

Comment: `app.get('/login.html',(req,res)=>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname+'/login.html')
    })`

Comment: @JaromandaX  Sorry! I am reading all the help. I didnt mean to be rude.

Comment: @JaromandaX _"First: do you have an application server?"_ The code is in the question. Have you even read the question? The second code snippet is the ExpressJs server.

Comment: @jabaa - yes, I have read it - I was asking the OP, since he responded "how do I do that" ... I'm gauging his level of knowledge

Comment: @ResinDeo - **you** weren't rude

Comment: @JaromandaX " First: do you have an application server? " , I do , it's in the code

Comment: @jabaa  , i'ma be honest I dont. I am having a tough time with it.

Comment: I gave you a code snippet in my comment. Add it before `app.get('/signupForm.html',(req,res)=>{` and start the server with `node signupForm.js`

Answer (score 0):

*"go-live"* starts a separated webserver, not your application server. One way  to solve your problem is to add a route to your applications server

```
const express=require("express")
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const bodyParser=require("body-parser")

const app=express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/SignUpData",{useNewUrlParser:true},{useUnifiedTopology:true})

const signupSchema={
    username:String,
    email:String,
    password:String,
}

const SignupInfo=mongoose.model("SignupInfo",signupSchema)

app.get('/signupForm.html',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/signupForm.html')
})

app.post('/signupForm.html',(req,res)=>{
    let signup=new SignupInfo({
        username:req.body.username,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password,
    })
    signup.save();
    res.redirect('/signupForm.html')
})

app.get('/login.html',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/login.html')
})

app.listen(5500,()=>{
    console.log("Server on 5500")
})
```

and start the application server with `node signupForm.js`.

Other ways to solve the problem are

- to use a webserver and configure it to handle POST requests or
- to start a webserver for `login.html` and to start your application server on different ports and to configure CORS headers or
- to start a webserver for `login.html` and to start your application server on different ports and to use a reverse proxy